# Ok to use Owl Carousel and Bootstrap 3?

Tags: owl-carousel

I noticed the owl carousel 1 demos are using bootstrap 2 (where applicable). Is it important to use bootstrap 2 with owl carousel 1, or can I use bootstrap 3 for styling? There is no information about this on the site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Bootstrap is only used for the site itself, and is not relevant to the use of the plugin.

Anyway, I'm using Owl Carousel (v2) with Bootstrap 3 without any problems.